# Dynamically(at some time intervals) change textures on a plane/cube in three.js?

Tags: time, three.js, textures, intervals

I know it's something with texture.needsUpdate() while rendering but I don't have a clue how to actually implement it. Maybe someone knows a link where I can see a working example or post some piece of code? Cheers.

Comment: what have you tried? are you having problems on the interval part (not three.js related) or updating the texture? See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates for the latter.

Comment: i think both. i want to build some sort of image slider on a plane(using three.js). so that for example after a few seconds texture changes to different image and so on(in a loop).And now i think that i might be wrong about the use of texture.needsUpdate().

Comment: Stack Overflow can't do the coding for you. I suggest you start doing the project (you can use pretty much any file from the examples folder as a template), then come back when you have more specific question.

Comment: ...but you can do it with some kind of timer in render loop or with window.setTimeout() or with window.setInterval(), anything will do. After changing the texture image you need to call `texture.needsUpdate = true;` to let Three.js know it is changed (it's a boolean, not a function).

Answer (score 1):

An excellent question; I created some sample code to do exactly this -- using a spritesheet to do some 2D animation on a plane and on a cube, which requires regular updates.  Here is a link to a documented example, that in particular contains a function to do exactly what you need.

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html

Hope it helps!